# this.state is NULL in ReactJs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a tutorial. I don't get why `totalCounters` is `null`. I searched online but I do not understand it.

The error message I get is :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'counters' of null.

I followed the tutorial from Mosh.

This is my `App.js` file.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar";
import Counters from "./components/counters";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar totalCounters={this.state.counters.length} />
        <main className="container">
          <Counters
            counters={this.counters}
            onReset={this.handleReset}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete}
          />
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my navbar.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
          Navbar <span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">{this.props.totalCounters}</span>
        </a>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

This is my counters.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";

class counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 5 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]
  };

  handleIncrement = counter => {
    const countersCopy = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = countersCopy.indexOf(counter);
    countersCopy[index] = { ...counter };
    countersCopy[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters: countersCopy });
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    const resetCounters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
      c.value = 0;
      return c;
    });
    this.setState({ counters: resetCounters });
  };

  handleDelete = counterId => {
    const newCounters = this.state.counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId);
    this.setState({ counters: newCounters });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleReset}
          className="btn btn-primary btn-sm m2"
        >
          Reset
        </button>
        {this.state.counters.map(counter => (
          <Counter
            key={counter.id}
            onDelete={this.props.onDelete}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
            counter={counter}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default counters;
```

Comment: I see you callings `this.state.counter.length` in your `<App />` component, but is there actually any state defined in it?

Comment: Also you don't define `this.counters`, `this.handleReset`, `this.handleIncrement`, ... in `App`. Why *would* that work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe those functions do work

Comment: @MichaelCacciano I don't see any state defined in it. but in the tutorial it works xd

Comment: Do they? Or do they just not throw an error and pass `undefined` to the child...

Comment: Yes they do work!

Answer (score 3):

In React, `this.state` is *local* to each component.

So, setting `this.state.counters` in `counters` does not allow `App` component to use the state.

This is why `counters` is null in `App` component.

Comment: How do I get the state.counters from the counters.jsx?

Comment: I'd suggest adding an `onChanged` event to `Counters` and then each time one of the `counters` is changed it would call this function on `Counters` props.  Then `App` can pass a function to this prop in order to receive the counters.  This is typically how it would work.  In React, props flow data down and events (functions) flow data up.

Comment: But if you are following a tutorial, and you are sure that the tutorial *should* work.  Make sure to go over it very carefully to make sure you are implementing the tutorial exactly the same way.  From your code, it looks like some of the functions are not connected in `App` that you pass to `Counters`.

Comment: Ah oki. Yeah the tutorial should work, at least it has 1 million views :P. I will see what I can do ! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have a state field into your `App` class components.
Everywhere you want to use state, you have to create a state object.

1. Class field

```
class App extends Component {
    state = { counters: [] }
}
```

2. Inside contructor

```
class App extends Component {
    contructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { counters: [] }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not initializing the state. Your `state` is undefined. Fix it like this

```
class App extends Component {

   this.state = { counters : [] } 
}
```